# How can I display all jobs and every job has it own company in one to many relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I try to build my own project which is job online website.

I have two tables `company` and `job`.Table `company` can have many jobs relationship

Here is relationship

```
//company.php
public function jobs(){
    return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
}
//job.php
public function company(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
```

​My tables

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('companyName');
    $table->string('logo')->nullable();
    $table->string('contactPerson');
    $table->string('employeeSize');
​    ...

Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('company_id');
    $table->string('jobTitle');
    $table->longText('jobDescription');
    $table->longText('jobRequirement');
    $table->date('deadline');
​    ...
```

​
I want to display all jobs and every job has its own company like

1. +in every list of  the job must have

   - jobTitle,
   - deadline,..and
   - companyName, logo

what is the code in controller and in the view would be?
please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access job's company by simply accessing **$job->company**. You could also optimise fetching data from the database with eager loading:

```
$jobs = Job::with('company')->get();

foreach ($jobs as $job) {
  echo $job->title;
  echo $job->company->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
public function index()
{

    $jobs = Job::all();

    return view('index', compact('jobs'))

}
```

View:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($jobs as $job)
        <li>{{$job->jobTitle}}</li>
        <li>{{$job->deadline}}</li>
        <li>{{$job->company->companyName}}</li>
        <li>{{$job->company->logo}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: This function work only job table any way thank for your help. It work with the first answer